# How to post jqGrid data along with other form values

Tags: asp.net-mvc, jqgrid

I have an HTML form containing some textboxes and two jqGrids. The user selects items from the first grid, and that moves them into the second grid. I want to submit the data from the textboxes, as well as the selected items (ie those in the second grid) as part of a FormCollection object back to my Controller. What would be the best way of doing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the serializeGridData option;

```
  serializeGridData: function(postdata) {
      return JSON.stringify({id: $("#id").val(), otherdata: $("#otherData").val(),  paging: postdata });
  },
```